# Why "on" Event Supports Delegation, But Its "Shortcut" Methods Don't?

Tags: jquery, jquery-events, event-delegation

According to [jQuery's API site](http://api.jquery.com), the `on()` event, when attached on a DOM node, supports delegation. As far as I can tell, this means you can have 2 DOM nodes, with the event starting at the inside node or somewhere inside it, then bubbling up to the outside node. Before this, and when you specify only one node to `on()`, the event bubbles up to the absolute outside node of the document, which is called `document` (and I believe the exact same thing happens if you have `document` as your "outside" DOM node). The "shortcut" events for `on()`, such as `click()` and `change()`, seem not to implement delegation, meaning the event has to bubble all the way up to the top of the document. If I've butchered this explanation, which I'm sure I have, please correct me. Why is this?

For example, I can have

```
$("form").on("click", "button", function() {
    window.location.href = "submit-page.php";
});
```

which is delegation, or

```
$("button").on("click", function() {
    window.location.href = "submit-page.php";
});
```

where the event would bubble out of the document. However, `click()`, for example, seems only able to have the 2nd form,

```
$("button").click(function() {
    window.location.href = "submit-page.php";
});
```

Comment: Your 1st and 2nd pieces of code are not identical. So that's why you see different behaviour. The `.click()` originally intended to not delegate but attach an event handler to a particular object.

Comment: Honestly, I don't really understand what you are asking for. Are you wondering how the shortcut methods are implemented? Or how event delegation works in general?

Comment: By the way, the 3 code samples were supposed to be an extremely simplistic representation of a form submit, in case anyone didn't get that.

Comment: @FelixKling I was asking why `on()` had those 2 variants but `click()` didn't, but I guess the answer, as it is so often, is "it's more complicated than that, they're not exactly the same".

Comment: Actually I think it's  due to API evolution. `click` had been a shortcut for `bind` originally, and we had `live` and later `delegate` for event delegation. But through that the API was quite fragmented. Now, with `on`, we have a single method to bind all kinds of event handlers but can still use `click` as before. It would not have made sense to extend `click` to support event delegation, it is already overloaded enough. But I'm not a jquery contributor, that's just how I would explain it.

Comment: I heard something about that, just didn't know the full history. It sounds reasonable enough. I think I will ask on the jQuery forum as Barmar suggested, to be safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.on()` ONLY supports delegation when used with two selectors as in:

```
$("#parent").on("click", "#child", fn);
```

The shortcuts like `.click()` don't support the two selector syntax and thus don't support delegation in the same way.

---

In your code examples, these two blocks of code do not have identical behavior:

```
$("form").on("click", "button", function() {
    window.location.href = "submit-page.php";
});

$("button").on("click", function() {
    window.location.href = "submit-page.php";
});
```

The first one uses event delegation and will respond to a propagated event that originated on a "button" object even if that button was added long after the event handler was added.  The second is direct event handling only and will only attach event handlers to objects that exist at the time the event handling code is initially run.  That's the difference between direct event handling and delegated event handling.

Another subtle difference is that the first one only responds to `button` events that are contained within a `form` (events propagate up through a `form` object) whereas the second one respond to events from any `button` in the page that existed at the time the event handler was installed even ones not in a `form`.

---

In your code examples, these two do have the same behavior (both are direct event handlers and will only work on objects that exist at the time the event handler is installed):

```
$("button").on("click", function() {
    window.location.href = "submit-page.php";
});

$("button").click(function() {
    window.location.href = "submit-page.php";
});
```

Comment: I knew I was butchering the explanation in SOME way. I'm kinda embarrassed I got almost that whole distinction wrong, though. Thanks for the BETTER description :).

Answer (score 1):

The `click` function used to be an alias for `bind`, before `on` existed.  `bind` would attach an event directly to the specified element.

More info on `bind` here: http://api.jquery.com/bind/

It looks like they never felt the need to extend the functionality beyond what was already there after `on` was added, and simply ported the internal code to use `on` instead of `bind`.

In either case, I generally just use `on` and skip the shortcut methods like `click`.

Comment: I generally skip the shortcut methods, too, because I like the idea of delegation & saw things saying it was better/faster (in certain places). I was just wondering why they didn't support delegation in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

There's no bubbling with the non-delegated methods. They just attach the handler to the specific element(s) that you bind them to. Bubbling is used by the delegation form of `on`: When you click on the button, the event bubbles up to the form. The generic handler that's attached there then checks whether the target of the event matches the selector argument, and in that case it runs the handler you supplied.

Delegation has more runtime overhead than normal binding, because the internal jQuery handler has to run whenever there's a click anywhere in the containing element -- it can't attach the handler to the more specific elements because they may not exist at the time you establish the binding. Since this is only needed in special circumstances, the shortcut syntax doesn't provide a way to do this.

You might want to submit a suggestion to the jQuery Forum. It probably wouldn't be too difficult to enhance the shortcut methods to allow syntax like:

```
$("form").click("button", function() { ... });
```

which would be short for:

```
$("form").on("click", "button", function() { ... });
```

As far as I can tell, this doesn't conflict with any existing syntax.

Comment: "Delegation has more overhead than normal binding" --- that's not that simple. You might have 1k elements and one handler with delegation, or 1k handlers per element without.

Comment: Good point. I was thinking of runtime overhead, i.e. all the times that the handler has to run unnecessarily because you clicked on the container but not on the specific element. This is especially true when programmers are lazy and use `$(document)` as the container.

Comment: There is more runtime overhead, but not necessarily how you described it. Whether you use event delegation or not, the event handler is always executed if the event somewhere within the element. The difference with event delegation is that an additional check will be performed whether a node within the "path" of the event matches the second selector. To be clear, I mean if the event handler is bound to the same element. Of course there is a difference between binding the handler directly to the element or to the delegated element (which seems to be what you meant).

Comment: But with non-delegated events, you attach the handler to the more specific element, e.g. the button, not the form. So nothing happens if you click on the form outside the button.

Comment: Yeah, edited my comment to reflect that. I guess there are just these two directions how you can compare the handlers.